# Malloc returns a pointer to a struct with the same address as another one

Tags: c, malloc

The purpose of my project is to create a virtual filesystem. The problem orcurres when I try to create a new subfolder for my root element. It returns a pointer to my root element and then "reallocs" that one.

Sadly I'm pretty inexperienced in C so I might forgot to add some details that you guys could need to help me so please don't hesitate to tell me what I forgot to add.

dataTypes.h:

```
#ifndef VFILESYSTEM_DATATYPES_H
#define VFILESYSTEM_DATATYPES_H

#include "vfilesystem_api.h"

typedef struct Folder Folder;
typedef struct File File;

struct Folder
{
    int32_t folderID;
    int32_t structSize;
    int32_t name_length;
    int32_t file_count;
    int32_t folder_count;
    char *name;
    Folder **parent;
    File **files;
    Folder **folders;
};

struct File
{
    int32_t fileID;
    int32_t structSize;
    int32_t name_length;
    int32_t size;
    char *name;
    Folder **parent;
    uint8_t *data;
};

#endif
```

create_filesystem_folder:

```
Folder *create_filesystem_new_folder(char *name, Folder *parent, FolderID folderID)
{
    Folder *folder = NULL;

    if ((folder = malloc(sizeof(Folder))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR || While creating new folder!\n");

        return NULL;
    }

    if((folder->name = calloc(strlen(name), sizeof(char*))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR || While creating new folder!\n");
        free(folder);

        return NULL;
    }

    if ((folder->parent = malloc(sizeof(folder->parent))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR || While creating new folder!\n");

        return NULL;
    }

    folder->folderID = folderID;
    folder->structSize = sizeof(Folder);

    folder->parent[0] = parent;

    folder->file_count = 0;
    folder->folder_count = 0;

    folder->name_length = (int32_t) strlen(name);

    strcpy(folder->name, name);

    folder->files = NULL;
    folder->folders = NULL;

    return folder;
}
```

Comment: Your first malloc should be malloc(..., sizeof(*folder)). Without the dereferencing its sizeof is only the length of the pointer instead of the struct

Comment: Same for the folder->parent, should be malloc(..., sizeof(*folder->parent))

Comment: The use of pointer-to-pointer is questionable. What are those pointer-to-pointers for? Generally, your program seems to suffer from not knowing when to allocate arrays and when to allocate arrays of pointers. I'd recommend to keep things simple and use common sense. Get rid of pointer-to-pointers.

Comment: Ok then I will simplfy it more I think that will suit me best here. Thanks for help

Comment: `struct file` has a definition in stdio.h   it also has a typedef for FILE.  So that is not a good set of names for your project

Comment: this line: `if((folder->name = calloc(strlen(name), sizeof(char*))) == NULL)` seems to be trying to allocate memory for an array of pointers to char arrays.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: There is no need (and it is undesirable in this scenario) to generate a `Folder_id` that is actually a `int32)t`.  Almost everything has the word `folder` in it.  That leads to confusion.  Suggest using unique names.

Comment: Thanks alot @user3629249 But FolderID is a predefined variable I'm not allowed to modify or change it for the project